# React no me aplica los estilos correctamente a un componente

Tags: css, reactjs, redux

Estoy trabajando con react y redux, lo que sucede es que el css no se me aplica correctamente a las imágenes de el componente las props se las paso por estado y el estado saca la información del servidor que tengo con express, el error solo pasa con las imágenes, el tamaño también varia y aun no entiendo como adjunto códigos y imágenes.
[image: Imagen de la template]

**Código CSS**
[image: Código CSS]**Archivo HTML**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Adjunta el código _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Esto no es react native. `style.countrie` debe estar regresando `nil`. Has tratado de simplemente poner `className="countrie"`?

Comment: Además para importar estilos solo necesitas `import './styles/styles.scss';`. Estoy seguro de que tu problema es que `style.countrie` es tomado como un objeto, y al tratar de llamar la propiedad `countrie`, da un resultado de `nil` o `undefined`. También el singular de `countries` es `country`.

Comment: @Jacobo en ninguna parte dice que sea raeact native, intente lo que me dijiste, pero solo empeoro y si fuera esa la razon cuando le paso height o width directamente deberia quedar, no?,  lo de country, gracias la vd me sirve bastante. pero lo demas nada sirvio.

Answer (score 0):

ya lo solucione, la solucion a los bordes, era solo cambiarle el padding que le estaba haciendo al top de la imagen por un margin, para que tuviera espacio pero por fuera de la caja, y los tama;os se solucionan con object-fit: cover;